# Drawing transparent image on WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, gdi+

I need to draw transparent PNG image on WinForms. I have a base class:

```
public abstract class BaseSkinable : Panel
    {
        protected BaseSkinable()
        {
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, true);
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, true);
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);
        }

    protected abstract void OnDraw(Graphics graphics);


    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= 0x00000020;
            return cp;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e) { }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {

        e.Graphics.TextRenderingHint =
            System.Drawing.Text.TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
        e.Graphics.InterpolationMode =
            System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        e.Graphics.PixelOffsetMode =
            System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
        e.Graphics.SmoothingMode =
            System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;

        OnDraw(e.Graphics);
    }
}
```

In inherited class:

```
    protected override void OnDraw(Graphics graphics)
    {

        Image toDraw = SelectImageToDraw();

        if (toDraw == null)
        {
            NoImageDraw(graphics);
            return;
        }

        int width = toDraw.Size.Width;
        int height = toDraw.Size.Height;
        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);

        graphics.DrawImage(toDraw, rect); 
    }
```

I need to redraw image if user move mouse over control. But the problem is against drawing overlay old image. Like we draw layers. Winforms possible not clear Graphics and my method draws over old picture. How to solve it, possible im doing something wrong.

Comment: So, you want to draw a png image to your panel control?

Comment: I have a PNG image with transparent. I need to make a "ImageButton" - the control what redraw an image while mouse enter, leave and click. So the problem is this ImageButton need to be transparent and with no borders.

Comment: You want to draw a transparent image on a Button. Behind the button is the `form`? Is `form` tranparent too?

Comment: I solved the problem. It was not trivial. If i put on form user control (contains images) and put over my ImageButton bug exists. If I put on form only images and put over ImageButton it draws corretly. I don know why.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to understand what your question is -- but are you trying to clear the background before drawing something?

Using the Graphics object, you can call Clear off of it with the background color.  If there is another image behind it, I can see some of your frustration -- but I would think you'd just need to set a transparent color (and supply the Transparent color to the Clear method).  That, in my mind, should clean everything up.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.clear%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Hope that helps or answers the question you were looking to get answered.

Comment: to call Clear() i need to use Color as paramert but i cant use it becouse i would not to fill backgroud. Color.Transparent is not works correctly

Comment: Have you set a ColorKey on the control, and can you use that Color?